# How to use group_by and summarize in R to do row sum

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df = data.frame("State" = c("AL","AL","AL","AL"), 
  "stateFIPS" = c(1,1,1,1), 
  "week1" = c(0,0,0,0),
  "week2" = c(0,0,0,0),
  "week3" = c(0,0,0,0))
```

Here is how my df looks like: There are week 1 to week 39

```
State stateFIPS week1 week2 week3
 AL         1     0     0     0
 AL         1     0     0     0
 AL         1     0     0     0
 AL         1     0     0     0
```

My goal is to add up each column based on different state code
Here is something that I just wrote:

```
covid_final <- covid_final%>%group_by(State)%>%summarise()
```

Comment: Please **don't** show your data as images but as the output of `dput`. You could do something like `covid_final%>%group_by(State)%>%summarise(across(starts_with("Week"), sum))`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
set.seed(1)
week1 = rpois(50,2)
week2 = rpois(50,6)
state = sample(c("a","b","c"),50,replace = TRUE)
df = data.frame(state,week1,week2)
apply(df[,-which(names(df) == "state")], 2, function(x){tapply(x, df$state, sum)})
```

This outputs:

```
  week1 week2
a    39    95
b    32   115
c    32    90
```

Which is exactly the sum of `week1` and `week2` grouped by `state`.
This is using base R, since I don't have much experience using dplyr.